# How to subtract 24 months from current date value and assign it to another variable?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two fields that are displaying from and To dates , I have a scenario i will populate To field `oplossDaterangeto` dynamically and from field `oplossDaterangefrom` will be set it to 24 months back from TO field.

How can i set from date 24 months back based on To date ?

main.html

```
<div class="row form-horizontal">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Daterangefrom" class="col-md-4 control-label">From:</label>
            <div class="col-md-7" ng-if="rcsaCycleDTO.oplossValDate">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5 changeWdh">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="oplossDaterangefrom" id="oplossDaterangefrom" kendo-date-picker ng-model="rcsaCycleDTO.oplossDaterangefrom" onkeydown="return false;" k-format="'MM/dd/yyyy'" k-min="'{{today}}'" ng-change="validateDate('oplossDaterangeto','oplossDaterangefrom')" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <label class="control-label padd15"> To:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 pull-right changeWdh">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="oplossDaterangeto" id="oplossDaterangeto" kendo-date-picker ng-model="rcsaCycleDTO.oplossDaterangeto" disabled/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Ctrl.js

```
$scope.oplossmaxdate = new Date('2015-01-15');
$scope.oplossmaxdate = $scope.oplossmaxdate.setMonth($scope.oplossmaxdate.getMonth() - 24);
$scope.oplossmaxdate = $filter('date')($scope.oplossmaxdate, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
console.log('date value :', $scope.oplossmaxdate);
$scope.oplossDaterangefrom = $scope.oplossmaxdate;
```

Comment: There are a lot useful Date functions in MomentJS library http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use get month to get the month and then subtract 24 from it.  If you then set month it will adjust back and change year and such.

Give d is of type Date:

```
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 24);
```

Documented here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth

Which notes

> If a parameter you specify is outside of the expected range,
>   setMonth() attempts to update the date information in the Date object
>   accordingly. For example, if you use 15 for monthValue, the year will
>   be incremented by 1, and 3 will be used for month.

So your code would look something like this:

```
oplossDaterangefrom = oplossDaterangeto;
oplossDaterangefrom.setMonth(oplossDaterangefrom.getMonth() - 24);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it helped.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to look into something like moment.js if this is something you are going to have to do a lot, it makes formatting, adding and subtracting dates very easy.  http://momentjs.com/

it would look something like this:

`$scope.oplossmaxdate = moment("20150115", "YYYYMMDD").subtract(24, 'months');`